# how to set labels from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have problem with set text on labels. Labels are declarated in class1 but I want to use it and set it in class2 where I want to set data dependent on the selected row in tableView (is implemented in class2)

my declatation in class1:

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *trackNameDetailsLabel;
```

my method in class2 (I try this but does not work):

```
-(void)setLabels {

    self.trackNameDetails = self.result.trackName; 
}
```

`result.trackName` is recall to data which are stored in url file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of you log this `self.result.trackName;` out is the data showing correctly?

Comment: I use something like this: `cell.trackNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.result.trackName]; ` in set labels in tableView and it works; and I want to set the same string in label in next view

Answer (score 0):

You can give class 2 a reference of class 1 from itself by making a variable like `Class1 *referenceOf1 = self` and adding `@class Class1;` to the top of Class 2. Then, in class 2, you can make an instance of class 1 and calling that reference.

Alternatively, you can pass data through a singleton, which in my opinion is nicer and avoids memory leaks. Here's a link to learn more about singletons.

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have trackNameDetails for class 2, but you want to set value to trackNameDetailsLabel in class 1
So the code

```
-(void)setLabels {

    self.trackNameDetails = self.result.trackName; 
}
```

will only set the property trackNameDetails in class 2.

You need give a reference, which can be instance of class 1 to class 2 like Cole said.
In class 2,

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) Class1 * class1;
-(void)setLabels {

   class1.trackNameDetails = self.result.trackName; 
}
```

Remember to set class1 to a instance of Class1 before using this method

Comment: I add in class2.m `@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailsViewController *detailsViewController;` DetailsViewController is my class1; in method setLabel i make `DetailsViewController.trackNameDetailsLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.result.trackName];` but now Xcode tell me that property trackNameDetailsLabe not found on object of type 'DetailsViewController' where I have declarations this Label.

Comment: Did you declare the the trackNameDetailsLabel property in class1's header file?

Comment: yes, I tried something like this `DetailsViewController *new = [[DetailsViewController alloc]init];
    new.trackNameDetailsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result.trackName];` but text isn't show on label but when I want to show in console it's work [`NSLog(@"%@", result.trackName);`]